# jdbc:script can not be executed when using *

Tags: java, spring

I try to execute some sql during initialization with below script in my appContext.xml. But the sql can not be executed when using * char. I am using spring 4.0 and hibernate 4.0.
Great thanks.

```
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="ALL">
      <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/h2/schema-*.sql" />
      <jdbc:script location="classpath:data/h2/import-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct version of Spring Batch but [check this documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch12s09.html)

Quoting from the doc:  The script locations can also be patterns with wildcards in the usual ant style used for resources in Spring (e.g. classpath*:/com/foo/**/sql/*-data.sql). If a pattern is used the scripts are executed in lexical order of their URL or filename.